# Index getting nil in view Controllers

Tags: ios, swift

Index of View controller in Navigation array always getting as nil. If i print arrayOfVCs, i can see the list of controllers still i am getting index as always nil

```
public func removeFromStack(controller :  UIViewController) -> () {
    if let currentWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let arrayOfVCs = (currentWindow.rootViewController as! 
            UINavigationController).viewControllers
        if let index =  arrayOfVCs.index(of: controller)  {
            (currentWindow.rootViewController as! 
             UINavigationController).viewControllers.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: Are you sure the array contains the ViewController which you wish to remove from stack?

Comment: yes i have cross verified..

Comment: @Sweeper 
self.navigationController?.removeFromStack(controller: UserProfileController.self())

and this "removeFromStack" is extension of navigationController

Comment: What is self()?

Comment: What happens if you `po controller`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i am calling from different view controller...
              func selectButtonAction(sender:UIButton!) {
                  self.navigationController?.removeFromStack(controller: 
                  UserProfileController.self())
               }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in an `extension`, `self` refers to the object that you are calling this extension method on, so you don't need to get the window, get the top VC and stuff like that. Just use `self`.

Also, you are passing `UserProfileController.self` into the method, which is not an object of view controller but a metatype. If you don't have an accessible VC instance and want to use the metatype to find the correct item to remove from the stack, you can change the extension to something like this:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func removeFromStack<T: UIViewController>(vcType: T.Type) {
        if let index = viewControllers.index(where: { type(of: $0) == vcType }) {
            viewControllers.remove(at: index)
        } else {
            print("Oops! The type of VC you specified is not in the stack!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Work Brother..
its works perfect.
For more my understanding ..
Could you explain the code which you have written..

Comment: Basically I find the first index of the view controller that has the same type as `T`, which is the type of VC you passed to this method. If there is such an index, I remove the item at that index. I used generics in this method. If you are not familiar with them, you can start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html @Shamil

Comment: I got issue after calling the removeFromStack Method.

Comment: Before Calling the method i am getting
po self.navigationController?.viewControllers
▿ Optional<Array<UIViewController>>
  ▿ some : 6 elements
    - 0 : <OscarCinemaMite.HomeController: 0x7fb0adc05a90>
    ▿ 1 : <OscarCinemaMite.MovieListController: 0x7fb0adc18a70>
    ▿ 2 : <OscarCinemaMite.CinemaListController: 0x7fb0b0220190>
    ▿ 3 : <OscarCinemaMite.ScheduleListController: 0x7fb0af06ca00>
    ▿ 4 : <OscarCinemaMite.SeatListController: 0x7fb0b00266d0>
    ▿ 5 : <OscarCinemaMite.UserProfileController: 0x7fb0b0029030>

Comment: After Calling the Method i am getting.

(lldb) po self.navigationController?.viewControllers
▿ Optional<Array<UIViewController>>
  ▿ some : 5 elements
    ▿ 0 : <OscarCinemaMite.MovieListController: 0x7fb0adc18a70>
    ▿ 1 : <OscarCinemaMite.CinemaListController: 0x7fb0b0220190>
    ▿ 2 : <OscarCinemaMite.ScheduleListController: 0x7fb0af06ca00>
    ▿ 3 : <OscarCinemaMite.SeatListController: 0x7fb0b00266d0>
    ▿ 4 : <OscarCinemaMite.UserProfileController: 0x7fb0b0029030>

Comment: But i am passing UserProfile as my controller.. why it is removing homeController then
Example..
(lldb) po vcType
OscarCinemaMite.UserProfileController

Comment: @Shamil does home controller inherit from user profile controller?

Comment: HomeController is the base controller. from there to the rest of controller it will go by push view controller.

Comment: I think the issue is with this line.
"let index = viewControllers.index(where: { $0 is T }"
Eventhough UserProfileController index is 5 ..
i am getting the index as 0, which is of HomeController

Comment: @Shamil NO, I mean in terms of class inheritance. Does `HomeController` inherit from `UserProfileController`?